Is there a way to minify .net or blazor wasm generated javascript?
I am using a MSAL auth library in blazor that generates the following js file
https://localhost:98333/_content/Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal/AuthenticationService.js
Blazor also generates javascript files like
https://localhost:98333/_content/BlazorJS/BlazorJS.lib.module.js
Is there a way to minify these files before generation? They are over 400kb each.
